# Inline function with one of two parameters as constexpr

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

Assume I have a function with two parameters where first parameter is dynamic but second parameter is always constant known at compile time:

```cpp
uint8_t convert_bcd(uint8_t num, uint8_t mask) {
    uint8_t result = mask & 0x0F & num;

    if constexpr ((mask & 0xF0) != 0) // mask is known at compile time, can be optimized
        result += 10 * ((mask & 0xF0 & num) >> 4);

    return result;
}
```

Example usage

```cpp
uint8_t result1 = convert_bcd(data[0], 0x7F);
uint8_t result2 = convert_bcd(data[1], 0x3F);
```

I would want to inline this function (if possible) and tell the compiler that the if condition, which involves only second parameter which always constant, can be resolved at compile time.

I got confused with `inline`/`const`/`constexpr` and how to apply them in my scenario to optimize the function as much as possible.

What is the proper idiomatic way to do it in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a template.

```
template<uint8_t mask>
uint8_t convert_bcd(uint8_t num) {
    uint8_t result = mask & 0x0F & num;

    if constexpr ((mask & 0xF0) != 0)
        result += 10 * ((mask & 0xF0 & num) >> 4);

    return result;
}


uint8_t result1 = convert_bcd<0x7F>(data[0]);
uint8_t result2 = convert_bcd<0x3F>(data[1]);
```

Comment: I type too slow.

Comment: A note salvaged from my proto-answer: The function doesn't necessarily know the parameter is a constant at the call site. Unless the compiler's being really smart and seeing every way the function can be used, it has to go with the general parameter, and that parameter can be different with every call.